# Git permission denied error while pushing a repository

Tags: git, github, push, permission-denied, credential-manager

I created a repository in my git hub account and came to git bash and
Pasted the command:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/ShreeramNew/RepositoryNow.git
git push -u origin master
```

And I got this Response

```
remote: Permission to ShreeramNew/RepositoryNow.git denied to ShreeramNew.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ShreeramNew/RepositoryNow.git/': 
       The requested URL returned error: 403
```

My account is Public.
I went to Credential manager, where only the default 'virtualapp/didlogical' credential was present.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check what credential helper you have:

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx (should be "manager" or "manager-core"
```

Check if your PAT ([classic Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic), with [scope repo](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/oauth-apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes)) is already register for that account:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ShreeramNew" | git credential-xxx get
```

If not, registers it:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=ShreeramNew\npassword=ghp_yyyyyyyy...yyy" | git credential-xxx store
```

Then try again your `git push`.